# MySql looking to see if user is banned C# Windowsform

Tags: c#, mysql

well i have a mysql database to store users on and stuff. i have a column that is account status.
like so
[picture is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I61h.png)

like right now i have made a admin panel so that i can change if they are banned ect. But at the login page i want it to check the username they put in and look at the status column to see if they are banned.

right now i have this code which does work but it dont really check it just says they whatever account i login to is banned.  any help would be amazing.

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=sql3.freesqldatabase.com; database=sql368409; Uid= ; Pwd=");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from sql368409.user where status='Banned'", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "status='Banned'");
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (dr.HasRows == true)
          {// to let them know they are banned
                UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                String externalIp = utf8.GetString(webClient.DownloadData("http://ipecho.net/plain"));
                MessageBox.Show(externalIp + "   Is BANNED From Using The Tool!!");
                break;
            }

        }

        if (dr.HasRows == false)
        {//if they are not banned. to log them in
            MySqlConnection con2 = new MySqlConnection("Server=sql3.freesqldatabase.com; database=sql368409 ; Uid=; Pwd=");
            MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sql368409.user WHERE username='" + this.textEdit1.Text + "' AND password='" + this.textEdit2.Text + "';", con2);
            MySqlDataReader myReader1;
            con2.Open();
            myReader1 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (myReader1.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;
                MessageBox.Show("Username and password is correct");
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong username and password");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please don't post links to external sites; when that picture goes away the question is meaningless.   Additionally, show what you've tried and what isn't working and what the problem is; it looks like you want someone to just write some logic for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, your code seems very insecure and dangerous. But other than security I'll tell you what's wrong and also what I would have done instead.

Your first problem is on row 2 and 3:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from sql368409.user where status='Banned'", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "status='Banned'");
```

It should read:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from sql368409.user where status='@status' and username='@username'", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("status", "Banned");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", this.textEdit1.Text);
```

I wouldn't use the textbox text directly but instead assign the value to a variable and check it first to make sure it "looks" like a real username but that's not what your question is about.

The code above should be what you need to get your current solution to work, but better would be to first get the user and then do the checks against him, like banned and password and such.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from sql368409.user where username='@username'", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", this.textEdit1.Text);

// First make sure we only got one row.
// Second check against password, otherwise return "bad credentials"
// Then check against banned, return "You're banned"
// Then maybe make him logged in as "admin"
// And such.
```